# How to delete a UITableView row when I press the delete button?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. I would like a delete button to be shown when I slide (swipe) the table cell. Then, once I press the delete button, the row will be deleted.

How am I going to be able to do that? Does anyone have an idea about this iPhone feature?

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: First, your question's title and body don't seem to ask for the same thing. Second, and more important, is that SO etiquette asks that you show us what you have already tried, and where exactly you are stuck. By doing that, we often get a much clearer picture of what exactly you're trying to achieve; and it shows that you've made an effort yourself. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have just a tableview. when i touch a tableview cell it push me a new Viewcontroller. Now in my tableview cell there is a 
cell.accessory symbol just like (>). i want, when i UIControlEventTouchDragInside the accessoryType symbol it will show me a accessory button(Just like delete Button). When i press the delete button. It will delete the row from the tableview.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [listArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just a tableview. when i touch a tableview cell it push me a new Viewcontroller. Now in my tableview cell there is a cell.accessory symbol just like (>). i want, when i UIControlEventTouchDragInside the accessoryType symbol it will show me a accessory button(Just like delete Button). When i press the delete button. It will delete the row from the tableview. 

How can i do this ???

Comment: If you include this method in your class file showing that tableview than you can see that delete button to delete the cell

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the corresponding data from your model (probably an `NSArray` your are based on to fill your tableView), in your implementation of `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. Then call `[tableView reloadData]` to ask the tableview to reload itself.

---

*Note: You can also use row insertion/deletion animation features (see documentation about `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:animation:`), **BUT** before trying to manage the row animation, you first need to know how to remove your model -- because they always have to be synchronized, and trying to play around with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:animations:`, without first manage to delete the row from your model successfully w/o animation, will surely make your app throw an InconsistencyException. So go one step after another, and start the basic step first, by modifying your model part of your MVC (your NSArray holding the data) before trying to go further!*

Comment: I have just a tableview. when i touch a tableview cell it push me a new Viewcontroller. Now in my tableview cell there is a cell.accessory symbol just like (>). i want, when i UIControlEventTouchDragInside the accessoryType symbol it will show me a accessory button(Just like delete Button). When i press the delete button. It will delete the row from the tableview. 
How can i do this ???

Comment: Then read the documentation and Apple's Programming Guide here, everything is explained in details and with sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1